# Does Android marketplace accept apps that are simply embedded websites (HTML/PHP etc.)?

Tags: android, google-play

I'd like to develop a "native app" for Android/IPhone.

To save development time, I would like to use an online HTML/PHP application to deliver the functionality and UI of the app. In Android, an embeddable browser can be achieved using WebView.

My app will not use any native-API specific functionality or devices(e.g. camera, geolocation).

Is it permissible to market an app Google Play that simply embeds a mobile friendly website?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, why wouldn't it? There is no specific filtering, apart from the obvious malicious.

Answer (score 1):

First off, this would not be a "native" app. It would be a cross-platform app.

There is no "Android Marketplace" -- do you mean the Google Play store? If so, yes, they will accept just about any app, provided you comply with their guidelines. For example, you can't sell in-app content through any means other than Google's own in-app purchasing.

That said, there's no solid php implementation for Android that I know of. The vast majority of the cross-platform apps utilize HTML/javascript. So much so, that there are quite a number of readily available frameworks available, such as PhoneGap, Sencha Touch, etc.